# Android send huge string as multipart to server

Tags: android, httpurlconnection, multipart

I'm wondering if it is possible to send a very, very huge string using multipart request to server. Is it possible to convert a string to a File object and vice versa because I can send an image via multipart request but as a `File`. How can I send string by a multipart request?

After converting the string to a byte and uploading it. How can i retrieve the file and convert it to a string?

Answer (score 2):

you have to work like this

```
public void connectForMultipart() throws Exception {
    con = (HttpURLConnection) ( new URL(url)).openConnection();
    con.setRequestMethod("POST");
    con.setDoInput(true);
    con.setDoOutput(true);
    con.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
    con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data; boundary=" + boundary);
    con.connect();
    os = con.getOutputStream();
}

public void addFormPart(String paramName, String value) throws Exception {
    writeParamData(paramName, value);
}

public void addFilePart(String paramName, String fileName, byte[] data) throws Exception {
    os.write( (delimiter + boundary + "\r\n").getBytes());
    os.write( ("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"" + paramName +  "\"; filename=\"" + fileName + "\"\r\n"  ).getBytes());
    os.write( ("Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n"  ).getBytes());
    os.write( ("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary\r\n"  ).getBytes());
    os.write("\r\n".getBytes());

    os.write(data);
    
    os.write("\r\n".getBytes());
}   
public void finishMultipart() throws Exception {
    os.write( (delimiter + boundary + delimiter + "\r\n").getBytes());
}
```

---

## update

for getting response

```
httpPost.setEntity(entity);
HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);

BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent(), "UTF-8"));



String sResponse;
while ((sResponse = reader.readLine()) != null) 
 {
     s = s.append(sResponse);
 }

 if(response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.SC_OK)
 {
     return s.toString();
 }else
 {
     return "{\"status\":\"false\",\"message\":\"Some error occurred\"}";
 }   
} catch (Exception e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

In place of image you can send anything, you would like to... if it creates some heck then
you should divide the large file into small parts then try to sending.And Join this small part on the server.

Comment: you didn't tell how to retrieve the string. how can I retrieve the string? how can i retrieve the request as string?

Comment: how can you tell that the `response.getEntity().getContent()` would return the `data` in the `addFilePart` and not the `value` in the `addFormPart`?

Comment: `response.getEntity().getContent()` It will return the `response` from the `Server`

Comment: i'm going to send the string to a jsp file. how? how can I get the request and write modifications in the jsp file?

Comment: but I'm already mentioned it in the "follow up question" or the description. btw, thanks. :)